# Remove whitespace after colon in algorithm2e caption

Tags: algorithm2e

I am using the `algorithm2e` package to visualize some algorithms in my thesis. If I use some figures or tables, the caption just goes the following way: "Figure x: some description here" or "Table x: some description here". Note that there **is no** whitespace before the colon and after the number.

If I use the `algorithm2e` package for a algorithm, it just prints the caption like the following way: "Algorithm x : some description here". Note that there **is** whitespace before the colon and after the number.

See my MWE which produces the following

[image]:

Is there anybody who can help me to remove that disturbing whitespace in front of the colon in the caption?

```
\usepackage[ngerman,boxed]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\SetAlCapSkip{1em}
\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Eingabe}
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Ausgabe}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
\caption{Encryption}
\label{alg:Cipher2encryption}
\KwInput{$e$, $k$}
\KwOutput{$a$}
\tcc{Runden 1 bis 2}
\For{i = 0 to 1}{
    Berechne $e = e \oplus k_i;$ \\
    Teile $e$ in 4 Teilblöcke $b_j$ zu je 4 Bit, sodass $e = b_0  \, || \, b_1  \, || \, b_2  \, || \, b_3$ \\
    Berechne $e = SBox(b_0) \, || \, SBox(b_1) \, || \, SBox(b_2) \, || \, SBox(b_3)$ \\
    Permutiere jedes Bit $e_k$, sodass $e = P_2(e)$ \\
}
\tcc{Letzte Runde}
Berechne $a = e \oplus k_2;$ \\
Teile $a$ in 4 Teilblöcke $b_j$ zu je 4 Bit, sodass $a = b_0  \, || \, b_1  \, || \, b_2  \, || \, b_3$ \\
Berechne $a = SBox(b_0) \, || \, SBox(b_1) \, || \, SBox(b_2) \, || \, SBox(b_3)$ \\
Berechne $a = a \oplus k_3$ \\
\end{algorithm}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a wrong definition in the code of that package for option `ngerman`.

As a workaround add the following three lines to your preamble of your given MWE:

```
\makeatletter 
  \renewcommand{\algocf@typo}{}% <======================================
\makeatother
```

You should contact the maintainer of that package to write a bug report ...

With the following corrected MWE

```
\documentclass[%
% ngerman
]{article}

\usepackage[%
  ngerman,
  boxed
]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\SetAlCapSkip{1em}
\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Eingabe}
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Ausgabe}
\makeatletter 
  \renewcommand{\algocf@typo}{}% <======================================
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
\caption{Encryption}\label{alg:Cipher2encryption}
\KwInput{$e$, $k$}
\KwOutput{$a$}
\tcc{Runden 1 bis 2}
\For{i = 0 to 1}{%
    Berechne $e = e \oplus k_i;$ \\
    Teile $e$ in 4 Teilblöcke $b_j$ zu je 4 Bit, sodass $e = b_0  \, || \, b_1  \, || \, b_2  \, || \, b_3$ \\
    Berechne $e = SBox(b_0) \, || \, SBox(b_1) \, || \, SBox(b_2) \, || \, SBox(b_3)$ \\
    Permutiere jedes Bit $e_k$, sodass $e = P_2(e)$ \\
}
\tcc{Letzte Runde}
Berechne $a = e \oplus k_2;$ \\
Teile $a$ in 4 Teilblöcke $b_j$ zu je 4 Bit, sodass $a = b_0  \, || \, b_1  \, || \, b_2  \, || \, b_3$ \\
Berechne $a = SBox(b_0) \, || \, SBox(b_1) \, || \, SBox(b_2) \, || \, SBox(b_3)$ \\
Berechne $a = a \oplus k_3$ \\
\end{algorithm}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: resulting algorithmn]

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I wanted.